# Delete a form - Visual Basic 2008 Express

Tags: vb.net, forms

I accidentally created a new form and want to delete it. Is there any way? I know this is very stupid, but I *really* need some help!

**Platform:** Visual Basic 2008 Express

Comment: i dont know why this was downvoted, the solution isn't obvious

Comment: I think it is obvious to the people who are quite experienced. But everyone has a starting point, don't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the extra form with code, just delete the code that you have entered.

If you added the extra form in Visual Basic Express, then you need to navigate to the solution explorer (usually the window on the top right), right click on the new form (Form2?) then click delete.